# High school probability question

Tags: probability, binomial-theorem, binomial-distribution

"Four six sided dice are thrown. Find the probability that the total score is 6."

Answer is: 5/648

I don't even know where to begin. This question was in our Binomial Probability (BP) homework but I don't know how BP would be applicable here?

Comment: You can being by listing the ways in which the 4 dice add up to 6...

Comment: {6, 0, 0, 0}, {5, 1, 0, 0}, {4, 1, 1, 0}, {4, 2, 0, 0}, {3, 1, 1, 1}, {3, 2, 1, 0}, {3, 3, 0, 0}, {2, 2, 1, 1}. These sets are unordered.

Comment: ^^^^^^^^^^ @Bram28

Comment: $0$ is not a possible outcome of a single die ... it's $1$ through $6$ ... so try again

Comment: Good point. {3, 1, 1, 1} and {2, 2, 1, 1} which can be permuted a total of 4C1 + 4C2 = 10 times. Each case has equal probability of (1/6)^4. Multiplying gives the answer. Thanks @Bram28

Comment: Yup, you got it! :)

Comment: Post that as an answer and accept it. @iso1234

Comment: You can answer it anyway (in case he won't) and there is a bronze badge for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two cases that need to be considered are {3, 1, 1, 1} and {2, 2, 1, 1} which can be permuted a total of 4C1 + 4C2 = 10 times. Each case has equal probability of (1/6)^4. Multiplying gives the answer.